# how to zoom an object on clicking on it. and zoom-inwhen esc key is pressed or close button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to zoom an object on clicking on it .  Clicking an image will zoom out the clicked image to its target-image. Click anywhere on the image or the close-button or press esc key to zoom the image back in.
It should look similar to this http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/image-zoom/#jquery-plugin-example

I've updated the code in http://jsfiddle.net/ErTqL/3/

Also as per the plug-in, if i remove the css, the images appear, and also zooming happens. but, the close button does not appear, & the esc key or clicking on the image does not close the Zoomed image.

I need an output similar to the plug-in. Also the zoomed image should occupy only 3/4th of the page as in the plug in, instead in my example, its extending to the entire page as if its the next page. Also refer this http://jsfiddle.net/ErTqL/4/ after removing the CSS of the plug-in. Kindly help as i'm a newbie for Jquery.

my code is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/JQuery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery.fn.imageZoom = function (conf) {
    // Some config. If you set dontFadeIn: 0 and hideClicked: 0 imgzoom will act exactly like fancyzoom
    var config = jQuery.extend({
        speed:            200,    // Animation-speed of zoom
        dontFadeIn:        1,        // 1 = Do not fade in, 0 = Do fade in
        hideClicked:    1,        // Whether to hide the image that was clicked to bring up the imgzoom
        imageMargin:    30,        // Margin from image-edge to window-edge if image is larger than screen
        className:        'jquery-image-zoom', 
        loading:        'Loading...'
    }, conf);
    config.doubleSpeed = config.speed / 4; // Used for fading in the close-button

    return this.click(function(e) {
        // Make sure the target-element is a link (or an element inside a link)
        var clickedElement    = jQuery(e.target); // The element that was actually clicked
        var clickedLink        = clickedElement.is('a') ? clickedElement : clickedElement.parents('a'); // If it's not an a, check if any of its parents is
            clickedLink        = (clickedLink && clickedLink.is('a') && clickedLink.attr('href').search(/(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|tif|tiff)$/gi) != -1) ? clickedLink : false; // If it was an a or child of an a, make sure it points to an image
        var clickedImg        = (clickedLink && clickedLink.find('img').length) ? clickedLink.find('img') : false; // See if the clicked link contains and image

        // Only continue if a link pointing to an image was clicked
        if (clickedLink) {
            // These functions are used when the imaeg starts and stops loading (displays either 'loading..' or fades out the clicked img slightly)
            clickedLink.oldText    = clickedLink.text();

            clickedLink.setLoadingImg = function () {
                if (clickedImg) {
                    clickedImg.css({opacity: '0.5'});
                }
                else {
                    clickedLink.text(config.loading);
                }
            };

            clickedLink.setNotLoadingImg = function () {
                if (clickedImg) {
                    clickedImg.css({opacity: '1'});
                }
                else {
                    clickedLink.text(clickedLink.oldText);
                }
            };

            // The URI to the image we are going to display
            var displayImgSrc = clickedLink.attr('href');

            // If an imgzoom wiv this image is already open dont do nathin
            if (jQuery('div.' + config.className + ' img[src="' + displayImgSrc + '"]').length) {
                return false;
            }

            // This function is run once the displayImgSrc-img has loaded (below)
            var preloadOnload = function (pload) {
                // The clicked-link is faded out during loading, fade it back in
                clickedLink.setNotLoadingImg();

                // Now set some vars we need
                var dimElement        = clickedImg ? clickedImg : clickedLink; // The element used to retrieve dimensions of imgzoom before zoom (either clicked link or img inside)
                var hideClicked        = clickedImg ? config.hideClicked : 0; // Whether to hide clicked link (set in config but always true for non-image-links)
                var offset            = dimElement.offset(); // Offset of clicked link (or image inside)
                var imgzoomBefore    = { // The dimensions of the imgzoom _before_ it is zoomed out
                    width:        dimElement.outerWidth(), 
                    height:        dimElement.outerHeight(), 
                    left:        offset.left, 
                    top:        offset.top/*, 
                    opacity:    config.dontFadeIn*/
                };
                var imgzoom            = jQuery('<div><img src="' + displayImgSrc + '" alt=""/></div>').css('position', 'absolute').appendTo(document.body); // We don't want any class-name or any other contents part from the image when we calculate the new dimensions of the imgzoom
                var imgzoomAfter    = { // The dimensions of the imgzoom _after_ it is zoomed out
                    width:        pload.width, 
                    height:        pload.height/*, 
                    opacity:    1*/
                };
                var windowDim = {
                    width:    jQuery(window).width(), 
                    height:    jQuery(window).height()
                };
                // Make sure imgzoom isn't wider than screen
                if (imgzoomAfter.width > (windowDim.width - config.imageMargin * 2)) {
                    var nWidth            = windowDim.width - config.imageMargin * 2;
                    imgzoomAfter.height    = (nWidth / imgzoomAfter.width) * imgzoomAfter.height;
                    imgzoomAfter.width    = nWidth;
                }
                // Now make sure it isn't taller
                if (imgzoomAfter.height > (windowDim.height - config.imageMargin * 2)) {
                    var nHeight            = windowDim.height - config.imageMargin * 2;
                    imgzoomAfter.width    = (nHeight / imgzoomAfter.height) * imgzoomAfter.width;
                    imgzoomAfter.height    = nHeight;
                }
                // Center imgzoom
                imgzoomAfter.left    = (windowDim.width - imgzoomAfter.width) / 2 + jQuery(window).scrollLeft();
                imgzoomAfter.top    = (windowDim.height - imgzoomAfter.height) / 2 + jQuery(window).scrollTop();
                var closeButton        = jQuery('<a href="#">Close</a>').appendTo(imgzoom).hide(); // The button that closes the imgzoom (we're adding this after the calculation of the dimensions)

                // Hide the clicked link if set so in config
                if (hideClicked) {
                    clickedLink.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }

                // Now animate the imgzoom from its small size to its large size, and then fade in the close-button
                imgzoom.addClass(config.className).css(imgzoomBefore).animate(imgzoomAfter, config.speed, function () {
                    closeButton.fadeIn(config.doubleSpeed);
                });

                // This function closes the imgzoom
                var hideImgzoom = function () {
                    closeButton.fadeOut(config.doubleSpeed, function () {
                        imgzoom.animate(imgzoomBefore, config.speed, function () {
                            clickedLink.css('visibility', 'visible');
                            imgzoom.remove();
                        });
                    });

                    return false;
                };

                // Close imgzoom when you click the closeButton or the imgzoom
                imgzoom.click(hideImgzoom);
                closeButton.click(hideImgzoom);
            };

            // Preload image
            var preload = new Image();

            preload.src = displayImgSrc;

            if (preload.complete) {
                preloadOnload(preload);
            }
            else {
                clickedLink.setLoadingImg();

                preload.onload = function () {
                    preloadOnload(preload);
                };
            }

            // Finally return false from the click so the browser doesn't actually follow the link...
            return false;
        }
    });
};

// Close image zooms when user hits esc
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        $('div.jquery-image-zoom a').click();
    }
});


</script>

<style type="text/css">
.total
{
border:1px solid black;
width:100%;
height:900px;   
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
}
.jquery-image-zoom
{
border:1px solid black;
width:98%;
height:100%;    
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;

}
.image_gallery
{
border:1px solid red;
width:100%;
height:27%;
}
.image_box
{
//border:1px solid blue;
width:33.1%;
height:100%;
float:left; 
}



</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="total">
<div id="jquery-image-zoom" class="jquery-image-zoom">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/bloodcells.jpg">Bloodcells</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/x-wing.jpg">X-Wing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/weve-moved.jpg">We've moved</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="image_gallery">
<div class="image_box"><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/lamp-and-mates/lamp-and-mates-01.jpg">  <img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/lamp-and-mates/lamp-and-mates-01_small.jpg" alt="Lamp and Mates" /> </a>  </div>
<div class="image_box">  <a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/stugan-winter.jpg"><img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/stugan-winter_small.jpg" alt="The Cottage - Winter time" alt="Lamp and Mates" /></a> </div>
<div class="image_box"> <a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/ps2.jpg"> <img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/ps2_small.jpg" alt="Lamp and Mates" /></a> </div>
</div>


<!--

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/lamp-and-mates/lamp-and-mates-01.jpg"><img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/lamp-and-mates/lamp-and-mates-01_small.jpg" alt="Lamp and Mates" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/stugan-winter.jpg"><img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/stugan-winter_small.jpg" alt="The Cottage - Winter time" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/ps2.jpg"><img src="http://exscale.se/__files/3d/ps2_small.jpg" alt="PS2" /></a></li>
</ul>
-->
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may i ask why are you building one on your own when there are hundreds of these plugins? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: how should i do that? in the link sent by you also there r no codes. Can u pls alter my codings in http://jsfiddle.net/ErTqL/3/ or show me some other alternate set of codes. pls help. me being a newbie i'm not able to proceed further. the link u sent is the correct output of my requirement. but how should i go about. pls help

Comment: check the examples - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples - you have both the HTML & Javascript code available.  Instructions how to 'install' it - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions

Comment: In reference to this link http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/6398/, i've copied the same codings, but still its not working. i've updated here. http://jsfiddle.net/j2AhV/2/. pls help. dont know where i'm going wrong or any tags i've missed

Comment: the first link is working fine for me on Chrome.  The second link, you didn't include the Javascript file of Fancybox (Add it through the External Resources tab on the left)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tKcVY/11/ is working fine in JSFiddle, but on my chrome, iam not getting the "close" symbol, & "previous & next" symbol. instead of the images, only words appear but they seem to work properly. i get words"close" on the top right corner of the image and if i click those words it closes,similar thing occurs with "previous & next" images also, it does not appear instead it works with the words itself. but why is the image not coming up.should i download the image separately or is there anything that i've missed. pls help.

Comment: i found the solution. thanks